# Is the sequence $a_{n}= {{n}\choose{[n/2]}}^{1/n}$ increasing?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, monotone-functions

Let the sequence $a_{n}= {{n}\choose{[n/2]}}$$^{1/n}$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, where $[x]=\max\{k \in \mathbb{Z} | k\leq x\}$ the floor function. How can I show that this sequence is increasing? I have tried using logarithms and gamma functions (for derivative) but I didn't get far. Any ideas?

Comment: You can get quite far by considering separately the cases that $n$ is odd and $n$ is even, and taking the quotient $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$. Simply expand the expression in terms of all the gory factorials, and then cancel terms. In the case that $n$ is even, this boils down to showing that $$\frac{2n+1}{(n+1)\binom{2n}{n}^{1/(2n)}} > 1$$ which looks easier?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the identity $k\cdot \binom{m}{k} = m\cdot \binom{m-1}{k-1}$ and apply induction over n by showing $a_{n+2} \ge a_n$.

For $n=2 $ & $ n=3:$$$ a_1 \le a_2 \le a_3 \Leftrightarrow \binom{1}{0} \le \sqrt{\binom{2}{1}} \le \binom{3}{1}^{1/3} \Leftrightarrow  1 \le \sqrt{2} \le 3^{1/3}$$

Given that the assumption is proven for n, we now need to show $a_{n+2} \ge a_n$. First reshape $a_{n+2}$:
$$ a_{n+2} = \binom{n+2}{[\frac{n}{2}+2]}^{\frac{1}{n+2}} = \bigg(\frac{[n/2]+1}{[n/2]+1}\binom{n+2}{[\frac{n}{2}]+1}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{n+2}} = \bigg((n+2) \binom{n+1}{[\frac{n}{2}]}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{n+2}} = 
\bigg((n+2)\frac{(n+1)}{(n+1) - [n/2])} \binom{n}{[\frac{n}{2}]}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{n+2}}
$$

Now check whether the inequality holds:
 $$
a_{n+2} \ge a_n\\
 \Leftrightarrow \bigg((n+2)\frac{(n+1)}{(n+1) - [n/2])} \binom{n}{[\frac{n}{2}]}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{n+2}} \ge \binom{n}{[n/2]}^\frac{1}{n} 
\\\Leftrightarrow 
\bigg(\bigg((n+2)\frac{(n+1)}{(n+1) - [n/2])} \binom{n}{[\frac{n}{2}]}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{n+2}} \bigg)^{n+2}
\ge
 \bigg(\binom{n}{[n/2]}^\frac{1}{n}\bigg)^{n+2} \\
\Leftrightarrow
(n+2)\frac{(n+1)}{(n+1) - [n/2])} \binom{n}{[\frac{n}{2}]}
\ge
\binom{n}{[n/2]} \cdot \binom{n}{[n/2]}^\frac{2}{n} \\
\Leftrightarrow
(n+2)\frac{(n+1)}{(n+1) - [n/2])} \ge \binom{n}{[n/2]}^\frac{2}{n}
$$

In this last inequality, the right hand side is smaller than 4, because
$$
a_n \le \bigg(\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}\bigg)^{1/n} = (2^n-1)^{1/n} \le (2^n)^{1/n} = 2
$$

And because in the left hand side in the inequality $(n+2) \ge 4$ for $n\ge 2$, and because the other factor is $\ge 1$, the statement is proofen.

Comment: You wrote 

$$ \bigg(\frac{[n/2]+1}{[n/2]+1}\binom{n+2}{[\frac{n}{2}]+1}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{n+2}} = \bigg(\color{blue}{(n+2)} \binom{n+1}{[\frac{n}{2}]}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{n+2}} 
$$

But there is an error.  The correct equality should be

$$ \bigg(\frac{[n/2]+1}{[n/2]+1}\binom{n+2}{[\frac{n}{2}]+1}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{n+2}} = \bigg(\color{blue}{\frac{n+2}{[n/2]+1}} \binom{n+1}{[\frac{n}{2}]}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{n+2}} 
$$

Comment: But why will this imply that $a_{n}$ is increasing? The sequence $a_{n} = \{5,1,6,2,7,3,...\}$ satisfies $a_{n} \leq a_{n+2}$ but it's not increasing.

Answer (score 0):

Use a stronger version of $$\left( \frac n k \right)^k < \binom n k $$ for $k < n$.

Alternatively, by Stirling's approximation $$ \binom {2n} n \sim \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}  $$

Comment: Thank you, Stirling's approximation will do! Just out of curiosity though, what's the stronger version of the above inequality you mentioned?

Comment: @Kon95 I believe the inequality as written just shows each term is $> \sqrt 2$ which is not enough. However, for large $n$, $k = n/2$ is much smaller than $n$, so the inequality can be made more precise.